# Do we have an answer for "Is there a problem with the Ubuntu repositories"

Tags: discussion

Over the past two days, I've noted that https://packages.ubuntu.com/ has been having a couple of issues.  Currently [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117986/cant-upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-to-18-04-1-lts-because-cant-upgrade-libbluray?noredirect=1#comment1847087_1117986) is looking for a package which *should* exists in xenial (libasm-java) and does exist in trusty and bionic.

I would tell the OP where to download the .deb file from directly, but cannot find a good link...

Comment: [This](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libasm-java) any help???

Comment: No we don't have one canonical answer/question combo because of the insane multitude of potential problem causes, esp. when you start going to country mirror levels.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a package-specific issue, something to do with `libasm-java` not existing in Xenial. There might be a reason, and there may be a way to step around this specific problem.

That said, I have submitted a rather generic answer about what *I would do*. Essentially torturing and executing every package blocking the upgrade. Once I'm  on the other side, just reinstall what I need. It requires an amount of technical confidence and there are cases where you would not want to follow it blindly.

I wouldn't suggest it's canonical. As Thomas said in the comments, I think there is just a bit too much variation out there to suggest one way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks Oli - This one seems strange to me because the libbluray-bdj exists both before and after xenial, but the dependencies are not the same between Ubuntu versions - Trust does not require libasm, Xenial requires libasm4-java, and Bionic requires libasm-java...  Personally I just reinstall rather than update, but again I'm a little lazy!

Comment: Yeah I'll happily concede there is something weird going on. It might be temporary, it's probably worth a bug report, but for the purposes of a release-upgrade it's easily remedied.